# How to change text-align of float field in odoo 9

Tags: python, css, xml, odoo

I got a float field in my model that left align when I put it in form view. My question is how to change it to right align.

I've tried so many ways to change its align to right but failed. I've tried to add `class="oe_right"`, create css custom module but not working. please help me

[image]

Comment: can you post an image?

Comment: Red underline in the bottom right is grand total value. it is a float field but left align. I think it have weird behavior, because float value should be right align not left align. I've create some tricks like custom css  to force it right align but still failed

Answer (score 2):

You can set text align right by give in-line style in particular field. Try following code.

**1. Right align of Float field**

```
<field name="field_name" style="text-align:right;"/>
```

**2. Right align of Float field value while edit mode**

You need to create custom css

File **base.css**

```
.openerp .oe_form_editable .oe_form .oe_form_field_float input{
text-align: right !important;}
```

**Add css to assets_common**

```
   <template id="assets_common_float_inherited" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href='/your_module_name/static/src/css/base.css'/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

Add xml file into **__openerp__.py**

Thanks.

Comment: thanks Jignesh for the answer, I've tried both of your trick and still not working :)